# Spring custom converter for all Enums

Tags: java, spring

I've built many Enum classes with `int getID()` and `MyEnum withID(int)` methods that allow me to dedicate an ID to the enum values for persistence purposes (thus avoiding changes due to order/name change with regards to external storage of the enum).

I'd like to build a custom converter that does some reflection to look for these methods, and use them or back up to Ordinal/String conversions when they are not found.

Does a generic Enum converter seem possible to anyone? This is only my second foray into Converters.

Comment: +1. I particularly like that you're _"avoiding changes due to order/name"_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd say you are trying to solve the wrong problem. I usually persist enums as Strings and thereby avoid this problem in the first place. The drawback is of course a larger DB field, but that's hardly significant.

---

That said:

I'd say it's possible in general, but not in a clean way. What I'd do is let all these enums implement a common interface (either just a marker interface or one that contains the `int getId()` method). Now register your PropertyEditor for this interface only, then you're not breaking too much standard functionality.

Then, your next problem is that you are relying on static factory methods, which can not be done in a generic way. Of course your PropertyEditor can do:

```
enumClass.getDeclaredMethod("withId", int.class).invoke(id)
```

but I'd call that very hacky. How about something like this:

```
Object target = null;
for(Object e : EnumSet.allOf(yourEnumClass)){
    if(e instanceof MyInterface && ((MyInterface)e).getId()==thisId){
        target = e;
        break;
    }
}
return target;
```

Now you are not using any static factory methods and you have compile time safety, as long as your enums implement a common interface.

---

**Update:** with the new Converter SPI it gets easier. Use [a custom ConverterFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-ConverterFactory-SPI):

```
public class CustomEnumConverterFactory implements
    ConverterFactory<String, Enum<?>>{

    @Override
    public <T extends Enum<?>> Converter<String, T> getConverter(
        final Class<T> targetType){
        return WithId.class.isAssignableFrom(targetType)
            ? new EnumWithIdConverter(targetType)
            : new StandardEnumConverter(targetType);
    }

}
```

Register it like this:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <!-- converters is a set of both converters and converterfactories -->
        <bean class="foo.bar.CustomEnumConverterFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Outstanding response. Thank you! One question, the Converter interface doesn't seem to give me any way to know what Enum type it is trying to convert the String into. You mentioned Property Editors, should I look into Property Editors rather than trying to use the newer Converter SPI in spring? A value of [1], for example, might be valid for 10 different Enum classes.

Comment: @David oh, my bad, I'm not too familiar with the converter SPI yet, I assumed you meant a PropertyEditor. Let me check :-)

Comment: Converter SPI is pretty simple, you just implement the interface: Converter<FromClass, ToClass> and register it. But the sole convert method it declares passes only the FromClass in and expects you to derive a ToClass. Thus no passing in Enum<?> or something like that. I thought maybe property editors provide a different way of handling things. I've never looked at them before.

Comment: @David see my update. Don't register a converter, register a converterfactory.

Comment: Oh Genius, you are my new SO God! :)  Thanks for pointing that out and making such an effort to help figure this out! I think this is the best response I've come across on SO hands down!

Comment: +1 for ConverterFactory - this let me delete a LOT of copied and pasted code (individual converters for common subtypes of an interface being implemented by individual enumerations).

Answer (score 5):

**Extended from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter**

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverterFactory(new ConverterFactory<String, Enum>() {
        @Override
        public <T extends Enum> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
            return source -> {
                try {
                    return (T) Enum.valueOf(targetType, source);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return targetType.getEnumConstants()[Integer.parseInt(source)];
                }
            };
        }
    });
    super.addFormatters(registry);
}
```