# Is it possible to have a spring model object as the value of spring form?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I basically have the following jsp which retrieves the advertisement objects which came with the spring model advertisement list ${myAdverts}.

And I would like that when one of those is clicked, a post request is submitted back to my controller but with an instance of the advertisement object. Is that somehow possible?

here is my JSP code:

```
<xc:forEach var="advertisement" items="${myAdverts}" varStatus="stats">
    <li>

    <a class="furtherinfo-link" onclick="javascript:submitJoin(${stats.count})" >${advertisement.getName()}</a>
    </li>
</xc:forEach>
<form:form id="myform" method="POST" action="form_submit.html" commandName="myForm" name="MyForm">
 <form:input id="advertisementObj" path="advertisementObj" type="hidden"/>
 </form:form>
```

here is my attempt to send the post back with javascript inspired by the handling of autopopulating lists in spring MVC and javascript:

javascript code

```
 <script src="js/webmenu_nav.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function submitJoin(position){
        $('#advertisementObj').val("myAdverts["+position+"]");

        document.MyForm.submit();
      }

</script>
```

The current behavior of that code is that I always get an empty advertisementObj on my post method in my Controller object.

The controller object is very simple, but just in case here it is part of its code:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value="/show_advertisements.html",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showAdv(@RequestParam(value="response", required=false) String incomingResponse) {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("response", incomingResponse);

    List<AdvertisementRecord> adverts = methodThatReturnsList();
    model.put("myAdverts", adverts);

    MyForm jform = new MyForm();
    model.put("myForm", jform);

    return new ModelAndView("show_advertisements", model) ;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/form_submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView formSubmit(MyForm myForm,  BindingResult result, Map model){


    if(null != myForm.getAdvertisement())
        return showPage("adver " + myForm.getAdvertisement().getId());
    else
        return showPage("null advertisement on join");


}

 }
```

**Solution!!**

snippets of the solution code

JSP code:

```
<xc:forEach var="advertisement" items="${myAdverts}" varStatus="stats">
    <li>
    <a class="furtherinfo-link" onclick="javascript:submitForm(${stats.count})" >${advertisement.getName()}</a>
    </li>
</xc:forEach>
<form:form method="POST" id="theForm" action="form_submit.html" modelAttribute="myAdverts" name="MyForm">
</form:form>
```

javascript:

```
<script src="js/webmenu_nav.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          function submitForm(position){
           $('#theForm').attr("action","form_submit.html?position="+position);

            document.MyForm.submit();
          }

    </script>

</head>
```

controller:

```
 @Controller
 @SessionAttributes("myAdverts")
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value="/show_advertisements.html",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showAdv(@RequestParam(value="response", required=false) String incomingResponse) {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("response", incomingResponse);

    List<AdvertisementRecord> adverts = methodThatReturnsList();
    model.put("myAdverts", adverts);

    //MyForm jform = new MyForm();
    //model.put("myForm", jform);

    return new ModelAndView("show_advertisements", model) ;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/form_submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView formSubmit(@RequestParam("position") final int position, @ModelAttribute("adverts") @Valid List<AdvertisementRecord> adverts,  BindingResult result, Map model){


    if(null != adverts && null != adverts.get(position))
        return showPage("adver " + adverts.get(position).getId());
    else
        return showPage("null advertisement ");


}

 }
```

Be aware on the code above, that it is important to have the request param coming first in the signature as Im calling "form_submit.html?position="+position"

Comment: it would make things easier if you post your controller.

Comment: @YevgeniyM. just pasted part of it, though there is nothing very fancy there. The real controller has a bunch more of RequestMappings pointing to different urls. And the form object just have an advertisement object which contains a couple of fields

Comment: thx, now we have a more complete picture of what you are doing and can provide better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

objects you put in your model are only there for the current request by default. It means your `myAdverts` list is not there any more in the second request (i.e. the POST request). However you can use `@SessionAttribute` annotation to tell spring mvc to store objects in the http-session, so you can access them in further requests.

your controller could look like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myAdverts")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value="...", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void get(ModelMap model){
        List myAdverts = // get your list of adverts.
        model.put("myAdverts", myAdverts)
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="...", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void post(@RequestParam("position") final int position, @ModelAttribute("myAdverts") List myAdverts,SessionStatus sessionStatus){
        myAdverts.get(position);
        // ...

        // tell spring to remove myAdverts from session
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
    }
}
```

for more information on `@SessionAttribute` take a look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib).

Comment: how long will the session attribute be stored? Is it possible to annotate it on the request mapped methods and have it relevant just to those methods?

Comment: @Thomas you deside how long myAdverts stays in session. To remove it from sesion you can inject a instance of SessionStatus in your post method and call setComplete() to remove myAdverts from session. i will edit my answer and put it in the code.

Comment: @Thomas myAdverts can be only injected in MyController... in your words it is relevant only there. But ofcourse the objects are located in session and can be accessed everywhere, where a reference to the session is present.

Comment: I'm now getting a "nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)" I'm wondering if Im missing something

Comment: @Thomas your model attribute is not called cisAdverts... it is myAdverts.

Comment: just got it! the RequestParam must come before the ModelAttribute in the method signature (or at least in case Im redirecting my method to uri?position=i  Thanks!!

Comment: regarding the cisAdverts, that was just a typo here when renaming variables for posting

Answer (score 0):

If advertisements have some kind of unique id and stored in a DAO(or there's another way to get an Advertisement from id), you can implement a converter that will take String argument and converts it back to the Advertisement

```
public class StringToAdvertisementConverter implements Converter<String, Advertisement> {

    private AdvertisementRepository advertisementRepository

    @Autowired
    public setAdvertisementRepository(AdvertisementRepository repository){
        this.advertisementRepositort = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Advertisement convert(String id) { 

         return advertisementRepository.lookup(id);
    }

}
```

after registering converter in the conversion service

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="my.StringToAdvertisementConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
```

your controller will be able to accept Advertisement class as a parameter of the `@RequestParam` and similar annotations:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/SomeMapping")
    public String handleSomething(@RequestParam(required = false) Advertisement advert,
        ModelMap model) {}
```

As an alternative, you can achieve the same results with PropertyEditors, there's [a good question on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter) with a lot of links to the Spring documentation.