# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth';

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am using spring mvc and Thymeleaf. Here is the html form for datetime-picker:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/created}" th:object="${customer}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">    
<div class="row edit-form">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label text-right">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="date" class="form-control"    
            th:field="*{dateOfBirth}" th:required="required" id="dateOfBirth"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In the controller i have:

```
  @RequestMapping(value ="/created",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String  submitNewCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer){
            customerService.createNewCustomer(customer);
            return "edit";
        }
```

and the Customer class is:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String firstname;
    String lastname;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    Date dateOfBirth;
    String username;
    String password;

}
```

Unfortunately, when i submit the form it complains with:

```
Field error in object 'customer' on field 'dateOfBirth': rejected value [2016-12-14]; codes [typeMismatch.customer.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [customer.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Temporal java.util.Date] for value '2016-12-14'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

So, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is solved when I changed the class to:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
Date dateOfBirth;
```

It seems that, it helps to convert string to more complex format like date.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698524/spring-mvc-with-jpa-databinding).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the @Temporal annotation

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date dateOfBirth;
```