# Mapping custom data type from URL to Spring MVC controller using @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring-mvc, data-binding, modelattribute

I am trying to send parameters from UI to Spring MVC controller. My parameter looks like

```
caseId=23951910&serviceProvided%5B0%5D.id=25989&serviceProvided%5B0%5D.desc=24-Hour+Service&serviceProvided%5B0%5D.duration=1&serviceProvided%5B0%5D.pages=--&serviceProvided%5B1%5D.id=25988&serviceProvided%5B1%5D.desc=3rd+Party+Contact&serviceProvided%5B1%5D.duration=2&serviceProvided%5B1%5D.pages=--&serviceProvided%5B2%5D.id=25980&serviceProvided%5B2%5D.desc=Advice&serviceProvided%5B2%5D.duration=3&serviceProvided%5B2%5D.pages=--&serviceProvided%5B3%5D.id=25982&serviceProvided%5B3%5D.desc=Document+Preparation&serviceProvided%5B3%5D.duration=4&serviceProvided%5B3%5D.pages=--&serviceProvided%5B4%5D.id=DOCREVIEW&serviceProvided%5B4%5D.desc=Document+Review&serviceProvided%5B4%5D.duration=5&serviceProvided%5B4%5D.pages=6
```

To match this parameter I am using custom class as

```
 Class MyDto {
   private Long caseId;
   private List<ServiceProvided> serviceProvided;
   //getter and setter
 }

  Class ServiceProvided {
    private String id;
    private String desc;
    private Long duration;
    private Long pages;
    //getter and setter
  }
```

I have controller as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cases/resolveClaim.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createClaim(@ModelAttribute("claimInfo") MyDto myDto, BindingResult result) { ... }
```

I am getting **404 error** so I am guessing "`serviceProvided`" list couldn't match to `myDto`. So my questions are:

1. Is this a really a reason I am getting 404 error?
2. If yes I guess I have to solve with [PropertyEditor or Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter)? Am I correct?
3. Is there any example code that I can refer to?

Thanks

Comment: how exactly the data is getting posted, it is not json type also.

Comment: 1. No. You will not get 404 error if the DTO doesn't bind, you are probably posting to the wrong URL or you are not issuing POST request.
2. You don't need to use anything extra to bind this DTO, from casual inspection of parameters, they seem ok to me and your POST should bind correctly when 1) is resolved.

Comment: @ ankur-singhal I don't understand what you asking.

Comment: @Kresimir Nesek URL is correct and request is POST. If I remove serviceProvided part from the request is works fine. <br/> Withour service part my URL is like http://locahost:8080/myapp/cases/resolveClaim.htm?caseId=23951910

Comment: Solved!!! I was getting 404 error since I was returning wrong view for this AJAX call. Also @ModelAttribute is quite enough to bind my UI fields to bean.