# Spring MVC: how to display formatted date values in JSP EL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

Here's a simple value bean annotated with Spring's new (as of 3.0) convenience  `@DateTimeFormat` annotation (which as I understand replaces the pre-3.0 need for custom `PropertyEditor`s as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12544479/225217)):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

public class Widget {
  private String name;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
  private LocalDate created;

  // getters/setters excluded
}
```

When biding the values from a form submission to this widget, the date format works flawlessly.  That is, only date strings in the `MM/dd/yyyy` format will convert successfully to actual `LocalDate` objects. Great, we're halfway there.

However, I would also like to be able to also display the created `LocalDate` property in a JSP view in the same `MM/dd/yyyy` format using JSP EL like so (assuming my spring controller added a widget attribute to the model):

```
${widget.created}
```

Unfortunately, this will only display the default `toString` format of `LocalDate` (in `yyyy-MM-dd` format).  I understand that if I use spring's form tags the date displays as desired:

```
<form:form commandName="widget">
  Widget created: <form:input path="created"/>
</form:form>
```

But I'd like to simply display the formatted date string without using the spring form tags.  Or even JSTL's `fmt:formatDate` tag.

Coming from Struts2, the `HttpServletRequest` was wrapped in a [`StrutsRequestWrapper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/StrutsRequestWrapper.html) which enabled EL expressions like this to actually interrogate the OGNL value stack.  So I'm wondering if spring provide something similar to this for allowing converters to execute?

**EDIT**

I also realize that when using spring's `eval` tag the date will display according the pattern defined in the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<spring:eval expression="widget.created"/>
```

Interestingly, when using a custom `PropertyEditor` to format the date, this tag does NOT invoke that `PropertyEditor`'s `getAsText` method and therefore defaults to the `DateFormat.SHORT` as [described in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat).  In any event, I'd still like to know if there is a way to achieve the date formatting without having to use a tag--only using standard JSP EL.

Comment: consider formatting the date in controller before handing over to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dispirited to learn that [spring developers have decided not to integrate Unified EL (the expression language used in JSP 2.1+) with Spring EL](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6080) stating:

> neither JSP nor JSF have a strong position in terms of our development focus anymore.

But taking inspiration from the JIRA ticket cited, I created a custom [ELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) which, if the resolved value is a `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.LocalDateTime`, will attempt to pull the `@DateTimeFormat` pattern value in order to format the returned `String` value.

Here's the `ELResolver` (along with the `ServletContextListener` used to bootstrap it):

```
    public class DateTimeFormatAwareElResolver extends ELResolver implements ServletContextListener {
      private final ThreadLocal<Boolean> isGetValueInProgress = new ThreadLocal<>();

      @Override
      public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).addELResolver(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

      @Override
      public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        try {
          if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isGetValueInProgress.get())) {
            return null;
          }

          isGetValueInProgress.set(Boolean.TRUE);
          Object value = context.getELResolver().getValue(context, base, property);
          if (value != null && isFormattableDate(value)) {
            String pattern = getDateTimeFormatPatternOrNull(base, property.toString());
            if (pattern != null) {
              return format(value, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));
            }
          }
          return value;
        }
        finally {
          isGetValueInProgress.remove();
        }
      }

      private boolean isFormattableDate(Object value) {
        return value instanceof LocalDate || value instanceof LocalDateTime;
      }

      private String format(Object localDateOrLocalDateTime, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        if (localDateOrLocalDateTime instanceof LocalDate) {
          return ((LocalDate)localDateOrLocalDateTime).format(formatter);
        }
        return ((LocalDateTime)localDateOrLocalDateTime).format(formatter);
      }

      private String getDateTimeFormatPatternOrNull(Object base, String property) {
        DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = getDateTimeFormatAnnotation(base, property);
        if (dateTimeFormat != null) {
          return dateTimeFormat.pattern();
        }

        return null;
      }

      private DateTimeFormat getDateTimeFormatAnnotation(Object base, String property) {
        DateTimeFormat dtf = getDateTimeFormatFieldAnnotation(base, property);
        return dtf != null ? dtf : getDateTimeFormatMethodAnnotation(base, property);
      }

      private DateTimeFormat getDateTimeFormatFieldAnnotation(Object base, String property) {
        try {
          if (base != null && property != null) {
            Field field = base.getClass().getDeclaredField(property);
            return field.getAnnotation(DateTimeFormat.class);
          }
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ignore) {
        }
        return null;
      }

      private DateTimeFormat getDateTimeFormatMethodAnnotation(Object base, String property) {
        try {
          if (base != null && property != null) {
            Method method = base.getClass().getMethod("get" + StringUtils.capitalize(property));
            return method.getAnnotation(DateTimeFormat.class);
          }
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException ignore) {
        }
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?> getType(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property, Object value) {
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isReadOnly(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public Iterator<FeatureDescriptor> getFeatureDescriptors(ELContext context, Object base) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?> getCommonPropertyType(ELContext context, Object base) {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Register the `ELResolver` in web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.company.el.DateTimeFormatAwareElResolver</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And now when I have `${widget.created}` in my jsp, the value displayed will be formatted according to the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation!

Additionally, if the `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` object is needed by the jsp (and not just the formatted String representation), you can still access the object itself using direct method invocation like: `${widget.getCreated()}`

Comment: In your solution, is **isGetValueInProgress** necessary, and if so why?

Comment: nevermind, found a comment in an old [github repo](https://github.com/pukkaone/webappenhance/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pukkaone/jsp/EscapeXmlELResolver.java) that led me to the purpose.
`// This resolver is in the original resolver chain. To prevent
// infinite recursion, set a flag to prevent this resolver from
// invoking the original resolver chain again when its turn in the
// chain comes around.`

Answer (score 9):

You may use the tag  to provide you these kind of formattings, such as money, data, time, and many others.

You may add on you JSP the reference: 
`<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

And use the formatting as:
`<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${now}" />`

Follows below a reference:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm

Comment: The `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>` taglib does not work with `java.time.LocalDate`

Answer (score 4):

To precise Eduardo answer:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${widget.created}" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I was hoping to be able to output the value directly without using JSTL's `fmt:formatDate` tag.  (And in any event this tag does not work when using `LocalDate` date objects.)

Comment: Why you don't want to use the JSTL?

Answer (score 3):

I also prefer to not do any formatting via tags. I realise this may not be the solution you are looking for and are looking for a way to do this via spring annotations. Nevertheless, In the past I've used the following work around:

Create a new getter with the following signature:

```
public String getCreatedDateDisplay
```

(You can alter the name of the getter if you prefer.)

Within the getter, format the `created` date attribute as desired using a formatter such as SimpleDateFormat.

Then you can call the following from your JSP

```
${widget.createDateDisplay}
```

Comment: This is a valid alternative.  Thanks for the answer.  But you're right--I'm really hoping that I can use Spring's `@DateTimeFormat` and declaratively get what I need in the view rather than have to do the work (imperatively) in the bean.  We're on the same page, though, because the end result of `${widget.createDateDisplay}` is very nice (especially when dealing with the newer `java.time.LocalDate` which does not play as nice with JSTL's fmt taglib).