# Angularjs : $resource - send Date as parameter

Tags: angularjs, spring

Is it possible to send a date to a Spring MVC api from Angularjs $resource?

I am doing this
Angularjs :

```
MyFactory.get({nomProduit:$scope.produit, dateDebut:$filter('date')($scope.dateDebut, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), dateFin:$filter('date')($scope.dateFin, 'yyyy-MM-dd')});
```

And Spring :

```
/**
     * GET  /rest/arrondis/:id -> get the "id" arrondi.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/statVenteProduit/{nomProduit}/{dateDebut}/{dateFin}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void statVenteProduit(@PathVariable String nomProduit, @PathVariable LocalDate dateDebut, @PathVariable LocalDate dateFin ) {
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date parsed;
            LocalDate dateDebut = null;
            LocalDate dateFin = null;
if (!dateDebutS.equals("null")){
                parsed = format.parse(dateDebutS);
                dateDebut = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(parsed.getTime());
            }
            if (!dateFinS.equals("null")){
                parsed = format.parse(dateFinS);
                dateFin = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(parsed.getTime());
            }
    }
```

I think this is quite dirty code.
Isn't it possible to send the two dates in a date format directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a custom date converter for LocalDate and define the parse pattern, then auto conversion should work fine.

See [CustomDateEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and [LocalDateConverter](http://unitstep.net/blog/2013/04/07/spring-mvc-request-parameter-conversion-with-minimal-configuration/)

Comment: Ok, thanks, once the converter is done, I don't get how to tell statVenteProduit to use this converter for the two params dateDebut, and dateFin.

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter) - Specially the last answer also shows how to convert the date only by using Annotations

Comment: Thanks I came to this last solution too.