# SpringMVC Custom Converter Not Found, But Declared in AppContext XML

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, converters

In my applicationContext.xml I declare the following 2 custom converters,

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="util.BooleanToYesNoDataTypeConverter"/>
            <bean class="util.YesNoDataTypeToBooleanConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The converters take care of converting between a Boolean and a custom type called 'YesNoDataType',

```
public class BooleanToYesNoDataTypeConverter implements Converter<Boolean,YesNoDataType> {

    @Override
    public YesNoDataType convert(Boolean source) {

        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(source))
            return YesNoDataType.Y_YES;
        else
            return YesNoDataType.N_NO;

    }

}

public class YesNoDataTypeToBooleanConverter implements Converter<YesNoDataType,Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean convert(YesNoDataType source) {

        if (YesNoDataType.Y_YES.equals(source))
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        else
            return Boolean.FALSE;

    }

}
```

In theory the Converters are now registered and can be used, right? I'm following the example in this post: [Spring MVC type conversion : PropertyEditor or Converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12544479/1005607)

However, in my Controller, when I come to the following initBinder override, I check my current active converters. Guess what, my 2 converters aren't available. Why is that? Take a look below.

```
   @Override
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

        // Check current ConversionService
        ConversionService conversionService = binder.getConversionService();
        // The below FAILS with a "Converter not found" error
        Boolean b = conversionService.convert(YesNoDataType.Y_YES, Boolean.class);
        // These 2 return FALSE, meaning we CAN'T convert YesNoDataType/Boolean
        System.out.println("Can convert YesNo -> Boolean? " + conversionService.canConvert(Boolean.class, YesNoDataType.class));
        System.out.println("Can convert Boolean -> YesNo? " + conversionService.canConvert(YesNoDataType.class, Boolean.class));

    }
```

By the way, let me ask a broader question about Spring/SpringMVC.  The Spring folks eliminated/closed a forum that existed until 2014, http://forum.spring.io/ . The only way to get SpringMVC support now is by posting here, on StackOverflow, but any SpringMVC threads here get 5-6 views and no answers. A few years ago the community was active. What's happened to SpringMVC, is it no longer well-supported? Where is the community for it? Just wondering.

Comment: are you using maven? if so have you tried cleaning your project and building again? sometimes it gets buggy, worth a shot :P

Comment: also check if your converters has @Component

Comment: Yes, I added @Component to the converters. Still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, the only thing that seems to work in my Controller is to cast the `ConversionService` to a `GenericConversionService` and then manually invoke `addConverter(...)` methods to add converters.

Now my conversion works. But this isn't the right way to do it -- all my XML registrations, incl. the @Component annotation on the Converter classes, should have worked. So the question is still open.

```
@Override
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

// Obtain a GenericConversionService via casting
GenericConversionService conversionService = (GenericConversionService)binder.getConversionService();
// Manually add converters on it
conversionService.addConverter(YesNoDataType.class, Boolean.class, new YesNoDataTypeToBooleanConverter());
conversionService.addConverter(Boolean.class, YesNoDataType.class, new BooleanToYesNoDataTypeConverter());

// Now it works -- these return TRUE
System.out.println("Can convert YesNo -> Boolean? " + conversionService.canConvert(Boolean.class, YesNoDataType.class));
System.out.println("Can convert Boolean -> YesNo? " + conversionService.canConvert(YesNoDataType.class, Boolean.class));
```