# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement the full calendar plugin in my webapp using Spring MVC, Java and MySql. I have been getting this error when I try to add a date using "input type = date" in my jsp:

```
Field error in object 'event' on field 'endDate': rejected value [2018-03-13]; 
codes [typeMismatch.event.endDate,typeMismatch.endDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [event.endDate,endDate]; arguments [];
default message [endDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' 
to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'endDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
java.util.Date for value '2018-03-13'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '2018-03-13']
```

In my controller class I am using SimpleDateFormat to format my date:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("event") Event event,
            HttpServletRequest request,ServletRequestDataBinder binder,
            ModelMap modelMap){
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
            event.setStartDate(simpleDateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("startDate")));
            event.setEndDate(simpleDateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("endDate")));

            eventService.create(event);
            return "redirect:../event.html";
        }catch (Exception e){
            modelMap.put("event", event);
            return "event/index";
        }   
    }
```

And finally in my Jsp:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Event Information</legend>
    <s:form method ="post" commandName = "event"
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/event/add.html">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><s:input path = "name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign = "top">Description</td>
                <td><s:textarea path = "description" cols = "20" rows = "5" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Start Date</td>
                <td><input type = "date" name = "startDate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>End Date</td>
                <td><input type = "date" name = "endDate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type = "submit" value = "Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </s:form>
    </fieldset>
```

Here is the DAO Implementation:

```
@Repository("eventDAO")
public class EventDAOImpl implements EventDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<EventEntity> findAll() {
        List <EventEntity> list = null;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session .beginTransaction();
            list = session.createQuery("select e.id as id, "
                    + "e.name as title, "
                    + "DATE_FORMAT(e.startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as start, "
                    + "DATE_FORMAT(e.endDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as end "
                    + "from Event e")
                    .setResultTransformer(
                            Transformers.aliasToBean(EventEntity.class))
                    .list();
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            list = null;
            if(transaction != null){
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

In my Entity class I have variables saved as a date so it is

```
private Date endDate;
```

I think the issue is with parsing of the Date but I am not sure! Any explanation of the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`@ModelAttribute("event") Event event` will make Spring try to bind the request value `2018-03-13` to the `private Date endDate` field inside `Event` type. Your conversion code won't be invoked because the error happens before the `add` method is invoked.

You need to either define a global conversion logic using `PropertyEditor` or `Converter` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter) or use `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` to specify the format for each date field:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
// or use @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private Date endDate;
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the @DateTimeFormat to be "dd-MM-yyyy"?

Comment: Yes, the standard patterns and placeholders from `SimpleDateFormat` apply. You also could read about `@InitBinder` annotation but I don't like this approach. I'd personally use `private LocalDate endDate;` and ensure that `java.time.LocalDate` is bound from a standard supported format.

Comment: With the java.time.localDate way, will I need to change anything in the DAO class?

Comment: You most likely want to replace `DATE_FORMAT(e.startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as start` with just `e.startDate` and handle `java.sql.Timestamp` returned by JDBC in Java. This `DATE_FORMAT` SQL function is a redundant cast to String which only complicates things. How will you map `java.sql.Timestamp` in Java is a different question but redundant operations can only lead to problems e.g. silent loss of precision.

Comment: So would I be changing the event.setDate in the Controller class? Apologies for all the questions, I am new to this and just trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

`request.getParameter("endDate")` returns String `"2018-03-13"`. You need to give matching format in `SimpleDateFormat`

```
simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
event.setEndDate(simpleDateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("endDate")));
```