# How can I get object fully from select component of Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I cannot get city object when I doing post. How can I get city object with Spring MVC?

`<form:select path="city">
    <form:options items="${cities}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
</form:select>`

[Response image Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl0rX.jpg)
When I post, I get this error.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Mon Sep 02 13:52:56 AZT
>   2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
>   Validation failed for object='user-form'. Error count: 1

```
-------------------- UserForm.java Class--------------------

public class UserForm{

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String attr;

    private int dictionaryId;

    private City city;

}


-------------------- Dictionary.java Class------------------------

public class Dictionary {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String attr;

}


-------------------- City.java Class------------------------

public class City {

    private int id;

    private String name;
}


-------------------- TestController.java Controller-----------------------

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class TestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public String getUser(Model model) throws Exception {
        List<Dictionary> dictionaries = new ArrayList<>();
        dictionaries.add(new Dictionary(1, "Ivan", "Ivanovic"));
        dictionaries.add(new Dictionary(2, "James", "Bulkivar"));
        dictionaries.add(new Dictionary(3, "Amanda", "Taylor"));

        List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
        cities.add(new City(1, "Baku"));
        cities.add(new City(2, "Istanbul"));
        cities.add(new City(3, "Moscow"));

        model.addAttribute("dictionaries", dictionaries);
        model.addAttribute("cities", cities);
        model.addAttribute("user-form", new UserForm());

        return "test";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/user")
    public String postUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user-form") UserForm userForm) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(userForm.toString());
    return "test";
    }
}`

---------------------------- test.jsp JSP---------------------------------

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>User</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form:form method="post" action="/test/user" modelAttribute="user-form">
                <form:label path="id">ID</form:label><br/>
                <form:input path="id"></form:input> <br/><br/>
                <form:label path="name">name</form:label><br/>
                <form:input path="name"></form:input> <br/><br/>
                <form:label path="attr">attr</form:label><br/>
                <form:input path="attr"></form:input> <br/><br/>
                <form:label path="dictionaryId">person</form:label><br/>
                <form:select path="dictionaryId">
                <form:options items="${dictionaries}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                </form:select> <br/><br/>
                <form:label path="city">city</form:label><br/>
                <form:select path="city">
                <form:options items="${cities}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
                </form:select> <br/><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use a converter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC type conversion : PropertyEditor or Converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter)