# Using ENUMs with FlatFileReader in Spring Batch job

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job set up to read in a CSV.

In the reader it creates ProductCSV objects which represent each row using FlatFileReader.

In the writer it then converts each row into an actual Object object which is mapped using hibernate into a database using an extended ItemWriter.

Works great the only problem I have is ENUM typed fields. The error I get is:

> Field error in object 'target' on field 'category': rejected value [Some Category]; codes [typeMismatch.target.category,typeMismatch.category,typeMismatch.com.project.enums.ProductCategory,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.category,category]; arguments []; default message [category]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.project.enums.ProductCategory' for property 'category'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.project.ProductCategory] for property 'category': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Here is what the ENUM looks like:

```
package com.project.enums;

public enum ProductCategory
{
    SomeCategory( "Some Category" ),
    AnotherCategory( "Another Category" );

    final String display;

    private ProductCategory( String display )
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return display;
    }
}
```

Here is what the ProductCSV object looks like:

```
package com.project.LoadSavingInfo;

import com.project.enums.ProductCategory;

public class ProductCSV
{
    private ProductCategory category;

    public ProductCategory getCategory()
    {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategory( ProductCategory category )
    {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Here is what the actual object looks like:

```
package com.project;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.project.enums.ProductCategory;

@Entity
@Table( name = "product" )
public class Product
{
    @Column( nullable = false )
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductCategory category;

    public ProductCategory getCategory()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory( ProductCategory category )
    {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

So when it reads in something like "Some Category" from the CSV, how do I convert this into the ENUM type? Any help or advice is greatly appreciated and if you need any more info please just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that standard Spring text->enum conversion is done using enum's name (`SomeCategory`,`AnotherCategory`) and not his `displayName`.
My advice is to convert enum's display name to ProductCategory object in your `ItemProcessor` as:

```
class MyItemProcessor<ProductCSV,Product> {
  public Product process(ProductCSV item) {
    Product p = new Product();

    p.setCategory(ProductCategory.fromDisplayName(item.getCategory());
  }
}
```

As side effect you have to declare

```
public class ProductCSV {
    private String category;
    public String getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }
    public void setCategory( String category ) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

You have the full process in your hand (and this is my preferred way, is cleaner).

Another solution is to use your current classes and write a custom enum property editor/converted as described in [Spring custom converter for all Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178622/spring-custom-converter-for-all-enums).